# Using post array in php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, http-post

I am trying my hand in php code, but I am having some trouble using the post array. I've tried to access the array so that I can put in MySQL but the array always ends up empty no matter what I try. Here is a copy of my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
//$comment=$_POST['Comment'];
require login.php; //Defines $host, $username, $password and $database with login credentials

$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();

if(isset($_POST[Comment]))
{
    $comment=getPost('Comment');
    echo "The comment is: $_POST[0]";
}
$date= getDate();
if(!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Comments(Date, Type, User, Comment) 
 VALUES ('$date[month]-$date[mday]-$date[year]', 0,'Jimmy Barrientos', '$comment')"))
{
    echo"INSERT failed: <br/>".mysql_error()."<br/><br/>";
}

echo <<<_END
<form action="addComment.php" method="get"><pre>
Comment<br/>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="Comment">
Type in comment here
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Add Comment"/>
</pre></form>
_END;

function getPost($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Number 1:** Put quotes around your string array index

```
if(isset($_POST["Comment"]))
                ^       ^
```

**Number 2:** Since you are using mysqli then MySQL_real_escape_string won't work, that is why you get everything blank. That would require a MySQL api based link resource which is not there. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
//   mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST[$var]);

if(isset($_POST["Comment"]))
{
    $comment=getPost('Comment',$con);
    echo "The comment is: $_POST[0]";
}
function getPost($var,$con)
{
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[$var]);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `$con` as an argument to `getPost()`, or delare it `global`.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried both of the changes, but it is still not working right. The MySQL entries are there, but the comment field appears blank, and the if statement is not being executed. It might be worth mentioning that I had similar problems with a simpler problem before that fixed themselves when I used the GET array, but I don't think that's the best idea here.

Comment: If that `if` statement is not being executed then the only reason is that there is no `Comment` field POSTed to this page. Try a `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 1):

You left out the quotes:

```
if(isset($_POST[Comment])) //<--- here
{
    $comment=getPost('Comment');
    echo "The comment is: $_POST[0]";
```

Comment: No, there is another ... :)